# We are having problems trying to send periodic messages to users of app

Tags: android, android-intent

I got the notification set up on a timer like the tracking, only to repeat every 20 seconds.

It shows the notification the during the first iteration and the logging shows that it goes through the code each 20 seconds, but the notification is not visible on the phone after the first time. Not sure why, Any thoughts?

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "App is running on this Phone. ", 1);

String title = "App";

Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MyActivity.class);
// set intent so it does not start a new activity  
notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

PendingIntent intent2 = PendingIntent.getActivity(getBaseContext(), 0,notificationIntent, 0);

notification.setLatestEventInfo(getBaseContext(), title, "App is running on this Phone. ", intent2);
//notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;

notificationManager.notify(0, notification);

Log.e("APP_DEBUG: doNotify finished", "APP_DEBUG: doNotify finished");
```

Comment: You aren't changing the notification id, is that intentional?

Comment: I didn't think leaving the id as 0 would matter, as it is the only notification we are using, and it is the same one to be displayed every day. My understanding is that it would over-write the older one. Do you think that is why I don't see the notification on the phone after the first iteration? I am not doing anything in code to cancel the notification; should I? I just assumed it went away after it finished displaying the text on the phone.

Comment: I'm not the best with this, but I think that if there's already a notification there, the contents of it will be replaced, but the user won't be notified again